# Is it possible to use std::regex and std::match_results with custom string type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am working on a project that has a custom string type, `MyString`. I can match on it just fine like this:

```
MyString getMatch() {
  static const std::regex MyRegularExpression(R"RX(^blah=([a-z0-9]+)$)RX");
  const MyString str = "blah=25";
  std::cmatch match;
  if (std::regex_match(str.GetConstCharPtr(), match, MyRegularExpression))
  {
    return MyString(match[1].str().c_str());
  }
  else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

But as you can see, I have to convert from `cmatch`s `std::string` back to `MyString` when returning the value. It's not a big deal at all, but I noticed that `std::match_results` is heavily templated, so I was wondered if it's possible to somehow put `MyString` to its template arguments to get match results already as `MyString`.

Is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: As long as your string type is a container that provides standard iterators, you should be able to sue that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use them, if you provide iterators, expected by those methods.

To use [regex_match](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) and [match_results](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results), your need to provide an iterator, which can be moved in both directions.

```
template< 
    class BidirIt,
    class Alloc, class CharT, class Traits >
bool regex_match( BidirIt first, BidirIt last,
              std::match_results<BidirIt,Alloc>& m,
              const std::basic_regex<CharT,Traits>& e,
              std::regex_constants::match_flag_type flags =
              std::regex_constants::match_default );

template<
    class BidirIt,
    class Alloc = std::allocator<std::sub_match<BidirIt>>
> class match_results;
```

Where,

> `BidirIt` must meet the requirements of [*LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator).

To meet requirement of iterator, means you should provide a class, which implements interface to increment, decrement and dereference iterator. The simplest example of iterator is a pointer, in case if your `MyString` stores all `chars` in a single array. To call `regex_match` you will need two pointers - at the beginning of array, and one pointing at the next after last element.